# Delete OpsWorks EC2 instance using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to delete an instance using this command:

```
aws opsworks delete-instance --instance-id i-04bcd091c06c14e86
```

But I'm getting an error:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteInstance operation: Please provide a valid OpsWorks instance ID, not an EC2 instance ID

I got the instance using

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | grep InstanceId
```

How do I get an opsworks instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the OpsWorks instance ID then you need to [use the OpsWorks version of the describe-instances command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/describe-instances.html):

```
aws opsworks describe-instances
```

**Edit:** If you just want to delete an EC2 instance that is not a part of a stack, use:

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids <instance-id>
```

Comment: That requires a stack-id it seems, which I don't have - I have an EC2 which is not part of a stack. Actually the only reason I use opsworks is because `aws ec2` doesn't have a delete-instance command so I assumed opsworks should be used.

Comment: If you aren't using opsworks to manage your servers, then no you wouldn't need to use opsworks to delete an instance. If you just want to delete an EC2 instance then the correct command is `aws ec2 terminate-instances`. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/terminate-instances.html

Comment: I edited your answer before accepting it. To explain, I used the opsworks command because I landed on it when googling how to delete an image. I didn't know that it's called terminating instead of deleting.